# How to take value from First array and generate second array and put the second array in the first array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried many ways to do this but no luck. I'm trying to take value from First array and generate second array and put the second array in the first array.

The code that I have now, generate the first array, in this array I have column called prereq_id I need to take this value and match it with courses table to bring its information in the courses table `course_id=prereq_id`. Any help would be highly appreciated

The array output is like this right now

```
[course_id] => 2 
[curriculum_id] => 1 
[set_number] => 0 
[course_code] => GCIS 516 
[course_name] => Data-Centric Concepts and Methods 
[credits] => 3
[semester_ava] => 2  
[prereq_id] => 10  
[set] => 3
```

**php**

```
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * 
                             FROM curriculumcourses  
                                  INNER JOIN courses ON curriculumcourses.course_id = courses.course_id 
                                  LEFT JOIN prerequisites ON courses.course_id=prerequisites.course_id  
                            WHERE curriculum_id='$ids' ");
?>

<?php
for ($x = 1; $x <= $mysqli->affected_rows; $x++) {
    $rows[] = $result2->fetch_assoc();

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rows);
echo "</pre>";
```

The result I need look like this

```
[course_id] => 2
[curriculum_id] => 1 
[set_number] => 0
[course_code] => GCIS 516 
[course_name] => Data-Centric Concepts and Methods
[credits] => 3 
[semester_ava] => 2
[prereq_id] => 10
[set] => 3 
[course_code] => GCIS 508 
[course_name] =>Database Management Systems
[credits] => 3
[semester_ava] => 1
```

Comment: What do you want your output to be, can you provide an output example just like you provided the current output?

Comment: Yes, off course @teodor-talov                                                                                         [course_id] => 2 [curriculum_id] => 1 [set_number] => 0 [course_code] => GCIS 516 [course_name] => Data-Centric Concepts and Methods [credits] => 3 [semester_ava] => 2 [prereq_id] => 10 [set] => 3 [course_code] => GCIS 508 [course_name] =>Database Management Systems [credits] => 3 [semester_ava] => 1

Comment: you just want some extra spaces beneath each element?

Comment: You can't have an array with two identical keys, e.g. `"course_code"`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Ja͢ck. Can I read the information from courses table for e.g. [course_code] and change the name in the array to be for e.g. like [prereq_code] ?